# Can you add a custom tradingview pine script to a screener?

Tags: pine-script

How to add a custom trading view pine-script to a screener?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What screener are you talking about?

Comment: There is a custom script in the public library in tradingview that I want to be able to use to filter stocks/forex pairs that meet a condition of the script.  Thank you.

Comment: No, the scriner can't work with custom indicators.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a simple pine script that screens for stocks from the pre-defined list that satisfy the condition set by the fucntion 'customFunc().

```
//@version=4
study("Manoj- Custom Screener", overlay = false)

// function that defines the condition
customFunc() => close > open

// list of stocks to screen from
s1  = security('BRITANNIA',  '1', customFunc())
s2  = security('MARUTI',  '1', customFunc())
s3  = security('NAUKRI' '1', customFunc())
s4  = security('PVR',  '1', customFunc())
s5  = security('NESTLE', '1', customFunc())
scr_label = 'Output : \n##########\n'
scr_label := s1  ? scr_label + 'BRITANNIA\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s2  ? scr_label + 'MARUTI\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s3  ? scr_label + 'NAUKRI\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s4  ? scr_label + 'PVR\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s5  ? scr_label + 'NESTLE\n' : scr_label

// set the label to display
lab_l = label.new(
  bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
  color=color.gray, 
  textcolor=color.black, 
  style =  label.style_labeldown,
  yloc = yloc.price)

label.delete(lab_l[1])
plot(0, transp = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to add alerts to the symbols and timeframe you want to screen. It is not as convenient as the screener, but atleast a workaround.